# What is a practical example of pooling?

Tags: computer-science, pool

What is a practical example of pooling? I understand from the wiki that pooling means to keep a set of resources ready to use. Where is this used? Any practical examples?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_(computer_science)

Answer (score 1):

A typical example of this is a [database connection pool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/). Usually, setting up a database connection is expensive. Web application threads use a connection to complete a web request and return the connection back to the connection pool, using a standard API. This is a justified use-case for object pooling.

Answer (score 0):

I use it all the time in Unity3D Engine. If I didn't, and instead destroyed many objects and re-instantiated them during runtime, the performance would be very stunted, and the decrease would be very noticeable.

Check out this video: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/object-pooling

In that scenario, he uses object pooling to avoid instantiating hundreds of projectiles.